# MySQL Full Text Search find NOT exact match

Tags: php, mysql

I can't find the answer to this on the internet, possibly because I don't know the right terms/jargon to search for.

I am using my own search function to get rows from my table.
I have three rows with columns with this input (without quotes):

```
"食"
"食べる"
"食糧"
```

Now, when I search for "`食`" I want the query to return all of these three results. But I only get the first one "`食`", the exact match returned in my query. How can I grab all of them?

My query:

```
  $sw = '食';
  $query = 'SELECT *, MATCH(word) AGAINST("'.$sw.'") as score FROM wordlist WHERE MATCH(word) AGAINST("'.$sw.'") ORDER BY score DESC;';
```

I appreciate all help.

Edit: Adding % doesn't work, like "%'.$sw.'%". None of the answers so far work either. :/

Comment: maybe `LIKE` suits you better in this particular case

Answer (score 1):

Use [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like):

```
 $sw = '食';
 $query = '
         SELECT *, MATCH(word) AGAINST("'.$sw.'") as score 
         FROM wordlist 
         WHERE work LIKE "'.$sw.'%" 
         ORDER BY score DESC';
```

Comment: This returns 0 results.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this,

```
'SELECT *, MATCH(word) AGAINST("'.$sw.'") as score FROM wordlist WHERE MATCH(word) LIKE '%'.$sw.'%'  ORDER BY score DESC;'
```

instead of your own query

Comment: Gives error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE "%食%" ORDER BY score DESC

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sw = '食';
$query = 'SELECT *, MATCH(word) AGAINST("'.$sw.'") as score FROM wordlist WHERE word LIKE "%'.$sw.'%" ORDER BY score DESC;';
```

In addition, you shuld check out escaping, sql injection and prepared statements.

Comment: This returns 0 results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use LIKE comparison but if you want to stay using MATCH() AGAINST() try with this:

```
    $sw = '食';
  $query = 'SELECT *, MATCH(word) AGAINST("+'.$sw.'") as score FROM wordlist WHERE MATCH(word) AGAINST("+'.$sw.'") ORDER BY score DESC;';
```

Comment: I'm actually already using + before the keyword. But it doesn't work. I still only get the first row returned.

Comment: You have a fulltext index in the column word? You can add with this:

ALTER TABLE wordlist ADD FULLTEXT(word);

Adding the index and using LIKE comparison the query should return the 3 rows (its working for me)

Comment: I do have this. Okay, it is very odd that it doesn't work for me then... :/ Thanks, if you have any more ideas, shoot :)